# Free tile provider for Leaflet

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet, tiles, data

I'm using Leaflet for the maps of my website. So far I was using maps of Mapbox (they're cool), but they obviously charge for them for website with 100,000+ maps per month.

I'm trying to find a provider of tiles which no charge for their tiles. Initially, I do it with OpenCycleMap, and substituted

https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

with

http://{s}.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

Two questions:

1) Does OpenCycleMap provide free tiles with no restriction of maps per month?

2) Does anybody know any other free provider?

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question.

Comment: You could just host your own, but you would also have to style them yourself, which might not be as comfortable as using an online editor, such as Mapbox.

Comment: About the licence, why not to follow the links from opencyclemap.org to http://www.thunderforest.com/terms/ and contact the owner of the service?

Answer (score 17):

You can simply use [Leaflet Provider](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/index.html) extension to pickup the tile works the best for your project.

Comment: ... or see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles for more OSM based tile sources.  But ALWAYS pay attention to each server terms of use ... don't break them by looting bandwith to much.

Answer (score 11):

As pointed out by [user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184), if you are using OpenCycleMap in an environment where the number of tiles you are requesting might be an issue, please check out the [terms and conditions](http://thunderforest.com/terms/) of the provider.

The [pricing schedule](http://thunderforest.com/pricing/) is publically available. Given the combination of [no-self-hosting](http://thunderforest.com/custom/) and the requirement for a non-free plan for a variation on the existing styles ("tweaked"), I think we can say that there is no site that offers what you've asked for (free tiles without restriction on maps-per-month, or other free provider).

There are other styles that you can self-host, or you could create your own.

Comment: Thank you very much. I should've googled "opencyclemap pricing" before asking any question.

I'll double-check the pricing plans of the tile providers to take a decision.